# Installing ownCloud in Synology NAS

Tags: linux, nas

I am trying to install ownCloud (Syno Community) in Synology DSM 6.0 I ended up with the following error. 
`Can't create or write into the data directory /volume1/owncloud` 
as I understand this is some permission issue.

May I please request for some suggestion here. Thanks for your time.!

Comment: Does the user you are running the installation as have write privileges on `/volume1/owncloud`?

Comment: @Taylor thanks for your input. I believe user doesn't have write priviledge on `/volume1/owncloud`. + Since I am using Synocommunity installation I think the privileges are to set explicitly. I tried chown but I still have the same problem. Could you please suggest a way out ?

Comment: `ls -lah /volume1/owncloud` and check the permissions, and `stat -c "%a %n" /volume1/owncloud` will tell you the octal permissions. Make sure the user can actually write to that folder.

Comment: `0 /volume1/owncloud` this is what I see after running the above command. Does this mean the privilege is granted.

Comment: I tried `sudo chmod -R /volume1/owncloud/` but still I get the same problem. Any suggestion..!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest following: install ownCloud in Docker. I think it gives one more flexibility. 
In docker, you also add/link folders from Synology NAS.